# Refactoring from if-else-if to Dictionary

Tags: c#

I have come across the following piece of code

```
 if (Region.Current == Region.EU)
    {
      return RegionalPriceLN;
    }
    else if (Region.Current == Region.NY)
    {
      return RegionalPriceNY;
    }
    else if (Region.Current == Region.HK)
    {
      return RegionalPriceHK;
    }
    else if (Region.Current == Region.TK)
    {
      return RegionalPriceTK;
    }

    return null;
```

And want to refactor it to use a Dictionary. Was thinking of something like below:

```
return Map.TryGetValue(Region.Current, out func) ? func() : null;
```

And the dictionary being initialized like this:

```
 Map = new Dictionary<Region, Func<double?>>
                             {
                               {Region.EU, () => RegionalPriceLN},
                               {Region.NY, () => RegionalPriceNY},
                               {Region.HK, () => RegionalPriceHK},
                               {Region.TK, () => RegionalPriceTK}
                             };
```

Another approach, to optimize memory usage would be to hold a static dictionary instead of an instance one:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Region, Func<TickingBasket, double?>> Map = new Dictionary<Region, Func<TickingBasket,double?>>
                             {
                               {Region.EU, t_ => t_.RegionalPriceLN},
                               {Region.NY, t_ => t_.RegionalPriceNY},
                               {Region.HK, t_ => t_.RegionalPriceHK},
                               {Region.TK, t_ => t_.RegionalPriceTK}
                             };
```

This would require for us to pass "this" to the delegate:

```
return Map.TryGetValue(Region.Current, out func) ? func(this) : null;
```

Can you think of a more elegant way to do this?

Regards.

UPDATE: Region is a reference type.

Comment: What is the rationale for storing anonymous functions rather than the objects themselves?

Comment: Your solution is concise, but it hurts my eyes to read it. Replacing the if/else if with a switch statement would simplify the code *slightly* but it would be very readable and easy to understand even for a novice programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Second option is definitely a preferred way over first one. Also you may consider a `switch` statement.

**UPDATE**. Since Region is a class then the only good way to avoid long `if...else` is the mapping like in your second variant

First option that you proposed (`Map = new Dictionary<Region, Func<double?>>`) requires the construction of `Dictionary` each time the method is executed. It is a waste of resources and time, and for this case even the `if..else..if..else` statements don't look that ugly :).

Second option (static `Dictionary` with fixed mappings) is a traditional way to branch the logic for your case. Moreover in certain cases [C# compiler will compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366376/are-net-switch-statements-hashed-or-indexed) the `switch` statement into static `Dictionary` to run lookups.

Comment: Switch is not possible because Region is a reference type.

Comment: You haven't provided the code for `Region`, and it looked like enum... Now that you mentioned it I see that you actually use `Region.Current`. So the only good option is your second variant

Comment: Have just updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: *"Second option is definitely a preferred way over first one."* Could you elaborate on this statement?

Comment: @MattDavey updated my answer

Comment: @almaz nice one, removed my downvote and added +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

To me. the design as far as I get it, seems a little bit smelly. I do not know engough of your code or the domain and your concrete implementations, but I would prefer other solutions to the dictionary-lookup or switch-statements.

Perhaps you could make use of the decorator-Pattern:

```
class Product
{
 // ...
    decimal price;
    decimal virtual Price
    {
        get
        {
            return price;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the EU-Region you generate an EU-Product-Decorator like

```
class EUProduct:Product
{
    Product product;

    //other stuff

    public override decimal Price
    {
        get
        {
            return Decimal.Multiply(product.Price,new decimal(1.15));
        }
    }

    public Region Region
    {
        get
        {
            return Region.EU;
        }
    }

    // more stuff to go        

    public EUProduct(Product product)
    {
        this.product = product;
    }
}
```

And the Class Region could be refactored to a simple Enum (as it goes along with your further domainlogic).

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you cant encapsulate this logic into `Region` class? Calling `Region.Current.GetPrice(basket)` (or, to go even further, `Region.Current.PricingStrategy.GetPrice(basket)`)  looks so much cleaner to me.

Or, at least, you can wrap your last line into an extension method.

Comment: That would make region aware of things it shouldn't be, and a possible violation of SRP. He could get away with it *IF* the Region and the Price were ALWAYS together. In this case it does not appear to be that way.

Comment: @Robert Snyder, thats why i'm asking :) For me its hard to tell from the code provided, what `Region` should and should not "know". Your explanation makes sense tho, this is probably the case.